# Salesforce Integration with Oracle

Tags: integration, callout, oracle, basics

I need to Integrate Salesforce with Oracle Platform (Create Account in Salesforce when its created in Oracle platform). I researched and understood that It could be done by API Callout methods.

Could someone help me with links/docs for Salesforce Integration using callout.

P.S : I have no knowledge in Coding, A basic step by step study material will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is REST API and not callout.

1. Callout - when salesforce initialises the transaction and sends/gets the information to/from external system. Here external system has to implement API/endpoint so that salesforce can access
2. Rest API - When External system initialises the transaction and sends/gets the information to/from salesforce. Here salesforce should implement API/endpoint so that external system can access exposed salesforce resources.

You can create apex method as below:

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
    global with sharing class AccountService {

      @HttpPost
        global static String doPost(String name,
            String phone, String website) {
            Account account = new Account();
            account.Name = name;
            account.phone = phone;
            account.website = website;
            insert account;
            return account.Id;
        }
    }
```

Before doing this you need to setup Outh - authorization.

References:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart.htm